# Displaying expressionengine entries in certain category with custom URL structure

Tags: php, expressionengine, categories

Let me explain, I have a website that I need to display a category structure that displays one category depth at a time, then when the final depth is reached, it will display the entries in that category.

The only way I have managed to do this is with using gwcodecategories. Using this I am outputting the depth into the url structure then using this segment to hard code what depth to display in my main page. Otherwise gwcodecategories will display every depth, you can't actually dynamically grab the current depth of categories depending on the current category.

This works great and I can cycle through all depths, however when I reach the final depth I thought it would be easy to output the entries in that category by adding a {if no_results} to my gwcode code. However this isn't working now because I have added a depth into my url... My URL structure is now:

www.website.com/products/list/(depth)/category/(category url title)

How can I display entries regardless of the URL? This is my code:

```
<div id="cat-filter">
<div id="products">
{exp:gwcode_categories 
    channel="product" 
    cat_url_title="{last_segment}" 
    depth="{if segment_3 == '1'}2{/if}{if segment_3 == '2'}3{/if}{if segment_3 == '3'}4{/if}{if segment_3 == '4'}5{/if}{if segment_3 == '5'}6{/if}" 
    style="linear" 
    id="category-items"
    }
    <div class="product-list{switch='|| no-margin'}"  onClick="location.href='{title_permalink='products/list/category/{cat_url_title}'}'">
        <a href="{path='products/view'}">
        {exp:imgsizer:size src="{cat_image}" width="190"}
        <img src="{sized}" width="{width}" alt="{title}" />
        {/exp:imgsizer:size}
        </a>

        <div class="prod-spacer"></div>
        <div class="product-info">
            <a href="{title_permalink='products/view'}"><p>{cat_name}</p></a>
            <a class="view-btn" href="{path='products/list/{depth}/category/{cat_url_title}'}">+ View Category</a>
        </div>
    </div><!-- END PRODUCTS LIST -->

    {if no_results}
    {embed="products/product_feed"}
    {/if}

{/exp:gwcode_categories}
</div><!-- END PRODUCTS -->
</div><!-- END CAT FILTER -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind sorry - got this working!

Moved my {depth} in my links to the end of the url so the url was then:

www.website.com/products/list/category/(category url title)/(depth)

This didn't interfere with expression engines parsing of urls as it was at the end of the url, then I just changed the if conditional to last_segment.

If anyone wishes to display categories like this, this is the only way I found out how to do it after hours of pulling my hair out.